# Best State Management Technique in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, redux, state-management

As there are many techs to achieve SM in Flutter....

Which will be best as a intermediate while developing a real world app??

Comment: Do not limit yourself to learning state management. But for development, a state management, due to its use in different parts of the application, makes it completely difficult and sometimes impossible to replace it after development. Looking to the future, you should choose not just simplicity of use. For example, Getx is easy to use, but replacing it with more handles will cost a lot more time than others (the chances of replacing it are also higher).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's depend upon you and your requirements. You have to maintain the state based in your scenario. All the package you mentioned, used different different approached for state management.

Answer (score 1):

As for starter try to learn Provider, it's simple. No need in learning another packages. Currently, I have 2 projects based only on Provider.